# htaccess to nginx (help)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to convert the code from the htaccess to Nginx but without any success, and yes i have tried all the online converter but it did not help, so can any here on stockoverflow help me please? I'm going crazy soon :-p **(Here is the code from the htaccess)**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.WEBSITE.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://WEBSITE.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Comment: Please put a sample URL for the last rewrite rule and the URL after being rewritten.

Comment: rewrite "^/([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$" /index.php?a=$1&q=$3 break;

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.website.com;
    return 301 $scheme://website.com;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
    root /path/to/root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/?([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/?.*$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$2 last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: Yes --> http://movie888.co/index.php am getting a error message when am trying to go to another page :/

Comment: Edited the regular expression. `/movie/586/The+Purge` will become `/index.php?a=movie&q=586` and `/genre/Comedy` will become `/index.php?a=genre&q=Comedy`. I guess that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much Fleshgrinder, the rewrite code you gave me the first time works, it was me that inputet it completley wrong, sorry about that hehe, but all worked great now...Thank you for helping me with this problem. :)

Comment: Last question, when i search for a movie like Shutter Island than the script only show that i have searched for shutter instead of shutter island, any idea how to fix that? Regards

Comment: Use a `form` around your search, the browser will then URL encode it automatically. And please mark my answer as the correct answer, to ensure that your question is not coming up in search results for unanswered questions.